# PHP DOM. Determine if an element is a descendant of another element in DOMxpath

Tags: php, dom, domxpath

How to check with DOM if an element is child (or grandchild, or grandgrandchild, etc.) of an other element?
I have the code:

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($this->dom); #$this->dom is DOMDocument object;
$clones = $xpath->evaluate("(//*[@".$this->cloneAttribute."])"); #get all clones
for($i=0; $i<$clones->length; ++$i) {
    $elems[$i]['path'] = $clones->item($i)->getNodePath();
    $elems[$i]['level'] = count(explode('/', $elems[$i]['path']));
}
print_r($elems);
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [path] => /html/body/section/header/ul/li
        [level] => 7
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [path] => /html/body/section/aside/div/ul/li[2]
        [level] => 8
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [path] => /html/body/section/aside/div/ul/li[2]/ul/li
        [level] => 10
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [path] => /html/body/section/main/section/fieldset
        [level] => 7
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [path] => /html/body/section/main/section/fieldset/ul/li
        [level] => 9
    )
)
```

In result I see that the fourth element inside the third element, and 2nd element inside 1st element.
Now I want to remove from array 4th and 2nd elements, because I need only parent elements.